How to get position of *content* of element in Javascript
I know about element.getBoundingClientRect().  It returns a DOMRect that contains the element including padding and border.  How can I get a similar thing which does not include the padding and border?
I want to know where the content of the element begins and ends (relative to the viewport ideally).

What about element.offsetTop?

@evolutionxbox offsetTop is worse (as in further from my aim of finding the content position), it includes margin too, and furthermore the result is relative to the offsetParent of the element, not to the page or the viewport.

Can't you just subtract the margin and padding from the overall value?

@ScottMarcus maybe I could do that, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to compute the margin and padding. And I was kind of expecting there would be some other simple way that I don't know about. That's why I'm asking.

padding and margin can be found using window.getComputedStyle(element)

As @evolutionxbox said, getComputedStyle() is the way to go. For example, let margin = getComputedStyle(element).margin

This is what I've come up with.
// Get the position and size of just the content part of an element (excluding margin, padding and borders)
const getContentBoundingRect = (ele) => {
    const st = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
    const b = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        left: b.left + parseFloat(st.borderLeftWidth) + parseFloat(st.paddingLeft),
        top: b.top + parseFloat(st.borderTopWidth) + parseFloat(st.paddingTop),
        width: b.width - parseFloat(st.borderLeftWidth) - parseFloat(st.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(st.borderRightWidth) - parseFloat(st.paddingRight),
        height: b.height - parseFloat(st.borderTopWidth) - parseFloat(st.paddingTop) - parseFloat(st.borderBottomWidth) - parseFloat(st.paddingBottom),
    };
};

It seems pretty complicated though.  Is there really no better way?

I'm not sure, but because CSS is all about the box model and the box model includes margins and padding, I think this is your best bet.
